# Is it possible to remotely debug a 64 bit machine from 32 bit Host Machine(which has visual studio)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have been through this article [Visual Studio 2010 remote debugging - Unable to connect: Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464809/visual-studio-2010-remote-debugging?rq=1) but has no menaingful output.

I am having following scenario:

**I have a Virtual Machine(VMWare) which has 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard OS and it is having an application installed which I want to debug.
and the host Machine(Windows 7 Professional 32 bit OS) has visual studio and source code. 
So, I am willing to debug the application which is installed on the VmWare(64 bit) machine from the host machine(which is 32 bit machine) using remote debugger of Microsoft.**

*Is it possible to do that??*

**In case, if it is not, then is there any workaround for this apart from upgrading the host machine(32 bit) machine to 64 bit Host Machine.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, the answer in the other article is incorrect, and you can debug x64 from an x86 host:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms184681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

> If you are debugging remotely, Visual Studio can run under WOW64 or on
>   a 32-bit computer. You can debug both IA64 and x64 applications, in
>   addition to 32-bit applications that are running under x64 WOW mode or
>   on 32-bit operating systems.

Comment: Frank, the issue is with the machine(not with the procees). yes we can do remote debuging for a 32-bit procees on 64-bit machine if host is also 64 bit OS but if host is 32 bit machine, then we cannot

Comment: or if it is possible, then pleae elobarte because I could not make anything from this msdn article